# Combine variables into one variable in R

Tags: r, reshape

Using `R 3.1` on windows. How can I combine variables `a.1`, `a.2` and `a.3` into one variable `a` excluding the missing values.

```
library(reshape2)
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                  a.1 = c(1,rep(NA,4)),
                  a.2 = c(NA,1, rep(NA,3)),
                  a.3 = c(NA,NA,1,1, NA),
)
```

I have tried using but gives `NA` values inside

```
dat$a <- paste(dat$conf.1,dat$conf.2,dat$conf.3, sep = "")

 id a.1 a.2 a.3      a
1  1   1  NA  NA  1NANA
2  2  NA   1  NA  NA1NA
3  3  NA  NA   1  NANA1
4  4  NA  NA   1  NANA1
5  5  NA  NA  NA NANANA
```

Comment: Combine means what?? you want to add,substract or pick unique ones?? what do you want want to do? your question is not clear

Comment: group variables `a.1`,`a.2` and `a.3` into one variable `a`

Comment: You need to include the desired result

Comment: And, perhaps, a more interesting example...

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(interaction(replace(dat[,-1], is.na(dat[,-1]), ""), sep="")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (dumb) way would be something like

```
dat$a <- as.numeric(apply(dat[, -1], 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]))
dat
#   id a.1 a.2 a.3  a
# 1  1   1  NA  NA  1
# 2  2  NA   1  NA  1
# 3  3  NA  NA   1  1
# 4  4  NA  NA   1  1
# 5  5  NA  NA  NA NA
```

Ot more general (if you have more than one value per column)

```
dat$a <- as.numeric(apply(dat[, -1], 1, function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = ",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
gsub(' |NA','',do.call(paste,dat))

1] "11" "21" "31" "41" "5"
```